# Total Area of different polygons in a table

Tags: qgis

I have a single table in which there is a column "Name" and want to find the total area of all those polygons where value of Name is Cardiff. I have more than one polygons with this name.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what have you tried so far?

Comment: With QGIS > 2.16 (?) you can achieve this using the sum function in the field calculator.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that by using GroupStat plugin.

Here you have a [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91895/how-to-sum-up-polygon-area-by-category) to similar question.

PS: A little advice from me, try to use search form before you post a questions.