# How to calculate or extract the area in square meter of different land use and land cover features within a Multi-ring buffer

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have created a multi-ring buffer in 100, 200, 300, 400 and 5000 meters around a point data, file  named as vector_buffer.shp.
Besides, I have also a raster layer with different land use and land cover class, file named, LULC.shp. I can clip the raster to the extent of the vector layer.

However, I am unable to calculate the area in square meter of the different land use and land cover features within each specific buffers.

My version is QGIS 3.22.10

Comment: LULC.shp... Shapefile isn't a raster format, it's a vector format. Are you sure it's a raster? Either way clipping the LULC as a vector is the best way to do this, you just need to calculate the area of the clipped polygons https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/calculating-polygon-areas-in-shapefile-using-qgis and summarize by land type https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/summing-data-from-column-in-attribute-table-in-qgis

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I have tried this technique but it turns out the total area within the buffer. What I am looking for is, the area for each land use type within each buffers.

Comment: You need a 'case' field, have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/91895/summing-polygon-area-by-category-using-qgis hopefully that plugin is still available. A case field becomes the rows, one for each unique value, then the statistics are the columns for each row.